# How to calculate with different columns of dates

Tags: r, date, time

I have a df called `t_compl` with three columns of dates.

```
date_op_indl    date_compl     usdato.x
1984-11-22  1984-11-22     1983-09-07
2004-11-16  NA             1994-10-27
1996-09-10  1996-09-10     1982-11-09
1986-05-24  1986-05-24     1982-11-22
1989-08-22  1989-06-13     1983-02-11
```

I want to create a fourth variable (`t_compl$time`) with the time difference between `usdato.x` and `date_compl` or `date_op_indl` in years. I want to choose the earliest date from `date_compl` and `date_op_indl`.

I have tried

```
t_compl$time<- ifelse((t_compl$date_compl-t_compl$usdato.x)<=(t_compl$date_op_indl-t_compl$usdato.x), ((t_compl$date_compl-t_compl$usdato.x)/365.25), ((t_compl$date_op_indl-t_compl$usdato.x)/365.25))
```

Because some `date_compl` are missing I want to use `compl_op_indl` for the calculation

```
t_compl$time[is.na(t_compl$time)] <- ((t_compl$date_op_indl-t_compl$usdato.x)/365.25)
```

and then get this error

```
Warning message:
In t_compl$time[is.na(t_compl$time)] <- ((t_compl$date_op_indl -  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

The time calculations also turn out completely wrong for the `compl_date` that were `NA`.

How to make this time difference calculation in R?

Comment: Do you want the result as whole years or years-months-days? `difftime` might be very useful for you here.

Comment: I need the exact time difference in time units. I choose years because I have an observation period of 30 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="date_op_indl    date_compl     usdato.x
1984-11-22  1984-11-22     1983-09-07
2004-11-16  NA             1994-10-27
1996-09-10  1996-09-10     1982-11-09
1986-05-24  1986-05-24     1982-11-22
1989-08-22  1989-06-13     1983-02-11", header=TRUE)

DF[] <- lapply(DF, as.Date)
```

Use `pmin` to calculate the minimum date for each observation (thereby ignoring `NA` values):

```
DF$time <- difftime(do.call(pmin, c(DF[, c("date_op_indl", "date_compl")], na.rm = TRUE)),
                    DF$usdato.x, units="days")
#   date_op_indl date_compl   usdato.x      time
# 1   1984-11-22 1984-11-22 1983-09-07  442 days
# 2   2004-11-16       <NA> 1994-10-27 3673 days
# 3   1996-09-10 1996-09-10 1982-11-09 5054 days
# 4   1986-05-24 1986-05-24 1982-11-22 1279 days
# 5   1989-08-22 1989-06-13 1983-02-11 2314 days
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach. I converted character to date then calculated the time difference. Since you said you would use year as unit, I have `/365` in `mutate`.

```
library(dplyr)

mydf %>%
    mutate_each(funs(as.Date(.))) %>%
    mutate(time = ifelse(date_compl %in% NA, (date_op_indl - usdato.x) / 365,
                     (date_compl - usdato.x) / 365))

#  date_op_indl date_compl   usdato.x      time
#1   1984-11-22 1984-11-22 1983-09-07  1.210959
#2   2004-11-16       <NA> 1994-10-27 10.063014
#3   1996-09-10 1996-09-10 1982-11-09 13.846575
#4   1986-05-24 1986-05-24 1982-11-22  3.504110
#5   1989-08-22 1989-06-13 1983-02-11  6.339726
```

Comment: And this one works as well:) Great to have more options!